# Generate two Visual Studio Solutions at same folder using CMake

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, cmake

Using CMake, I am trying to this:

Create two Visual Studio solutions at same folder.

eg.:

```
root
|
|-- myproject.sln
|-- myproject_x64.sln
```

Generated with command line (.bat file):

```
cmake -G"Visual Studio 10"
del CMakeCache.txt // POG to generate win64 in the sequence "CMake ZERO_CHECK will cry"
cmake -G"Visual Studio 10 Win64"
```

Inside cmake file:

```
PROJECT(myproject)

IF(NOT "${CMAKE_CL_64}" MATCHES "0")
    MESSAGE( STATUS "Generating x64 Solution...")
    PROJECT(myproject_x64)
ELSE()
    MESSAGE( STATUS "Generating x86 Solution...")
ENDIF()

(...)
```

Is it possible to do something like this ?

The CMake always generate ALL_BUILD project resulting this:

```
root
|-- source/header files
|-- unittest.vcxproj
|
|-- ALL_BUILD.vcxproj (used for last generated project)
|-- myproject.sln
|-- myproject_x64.sln
```

Is there a way to create subdirectories for (ALL_BUILD.vcxproj,INSTALL.vcxproj,PACKAGE.vcxproj, ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj) ?

eg.:

```
root
|-- source/header files
|-- unittest.vcxproj
|
|-- myproject.sln
|-- myproject_x64.sln
|
|---- depDir
        |
        | (used for myproject)
        |-- ALL_BUILD.vcxproj 
        |-- INSTALL.vcxproj
        |-- PACKAGE.vcxproj
        |-- ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj
|---- depDir_x64
        |
        | (used for myproject_x64)
        |-- ALL_BUILD.vcxproj 
        |-- INSTALL.vcxproj
        |-- PACKAGE.vcxproj
        |-- ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj
```

OR "preferable"

```
root
|-- source/header files
|-- unittest.vcxproj
|
|-- myproject.sln
|-- myproject_x64.sln
|
|-- ALL_BUILD.vcxproj (used for myproject)
|-- INSTALL.vcxproj (used for myproject)
|-- PACKAGE.vcxproj (used for myproject)
|-- ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj
|
|---- depDir_x64
        |
        | (used for myproject_x64)
        |-- Additional CMakeLists.txt if needed.
        |-- ALL_BUILD.vcxproj 
        |-- INSTALL.vcxproj
        |-- PACKAGE.vcxproj
        |-- ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj
```

Is it possible to do something like this ?

Comment: I think you'll be fighting CMake more than using it. What would be the advantage over having a separate x86 and x64 build folder?

Comment: As CMake does not allow configure (Win32 and x64) option in the same ".sln" file using separate folders may not conflict with the file (ALL_BUILD.vcxproj) of the two projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good alternative!

I create a .bat file to generate x86, x64 folders and use a single CMakeLists file.

```
@echo off
echo Generating x86 Solution...

mkdir x86
cd x86
cmake -G"Visual Studio 10" "../"
cd ..
mkshortcut "../" /target:"%~dp0\x86\myproject.sln" /shortcut:"myproject.sln"

echo Generating x64 Solution...

mkdir x64
cd x64
cmake -G"Visual Studio 10 Win64" "../"
cd ..
mkshortcut "../" /target:"%~dp0\x64\myproject.sln" /shortcut:"myproject_x64.sln"

pause
```

Using

```
cd x86
```

and

```
cmake "../"
```

I can generate files inside x86 folder.

The result is:

```
root
|-- source/header files
|-- x86 <- folder
|-- x64 <- folder
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- myproject.sln <-shortcut to x86 .sln
|-- myproject_x64.sln <-shortcut to x64 .sln
```

The code to create shortcut file

```
mkshortcut "../" /target:"%~dp0\x86\myproject.sln" /shortcut:"myproject.sln"
```

Uses mkshortcut.vbs taken from [giannistsakiris.com](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2008/12/03/how-to-create-shortcuts-in-windows-from-the-command-line/)

```
rem This code is used to generate files shortcuts
rem eg.:
rem mkshortcut /target:"c:\myfile" /shortcut:"c:\myfileShortcut"

set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell" )
set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(Wscript.Arguments.Named("shortcut") & ".lnk")
oShellLink.TargetPath = Wscript.Arguments.Named("target")
oShellLink.WindowStyle = 1
oShellLink.Save
```

To see if cmake -G"Visual Studio 10 Win64" was used:

```
IF(NOT "${CMAKE_CL_64}" MATCHES "0")
...
```